# I want to update a column using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is a query. I want `bookdate_to` to be updated.

```
SELECT
    r.resource_id,
    r.type,
    r.resort_id,
    r.parent_id,
    r.code,
    r.name,
    r.path,
    r.cashflowmanager_id,
    c.bookdate_from,
    c.bookdate_to,
    c.usage_date_from,
    c.usage_date_to
FROM
    resourcebasei18n   r
    JOIN cashflowrule       c ON ( r.cashflowmanager_id = c.cashflowmanager_id )
WHERE
    name = '4-Persoons Ranchtent'
    AND ( c.usage_date_from BETWEEN '01-APR-20' AND '01-MAY-20'
          OR c.usage_date_to BETWEEN '01-APR-20' AND '01-MAY-20' );
```

I want a proper plsql code using procedure or loop that updates all records of column `bookdate_to`.

Comment: This is a SELECT statement. UPDATE ... well, *updates* something. What should the column be updated to? Does it have to be PL/SQL (I'm asking because in many cases SQL can handle that)? By the way, in WHERE clause you seem to be comparing dates to strings (`'01-APR-20'` is a string; use date literal `date 2020-04-01'` instead).

Comment: ok dont use date as string just ignore that and i want date to be updated as 0(zero). But I want that in plsql

Comment: *all* bookdate_from values should be set to null in a table?

Comment: sample data and expected output will help here, as your statement "i want date to be updated as 0(zero)" is unclear -- date can't be updated to 0.

Comment: I want book_to date to be anything but not date and NULL i just want to update column any how you can give space as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "to be anything but not date and NULL"?

Comment: give date '29-SEP-2019'

Comment: in the given above query how can we update column bookdate_to to 29-SEP-2019.By using plsql blocks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for PL/SQL loops. We can do this in plain SQL:

```
update cashflowrule c 
set    c.bookdate_to = date '2019-09-29'
where  ( c.usage_date_from BETWEEN date '2020-04-01' AND date '2020-05-01'
      OR c.usage_date_to   BETWEEN date '2020-04-01' AND date '2020-05-01' )
and    c.bookdate_to is null -- not sure whether this is a rule, your comments confuse me
and    c.cashflowmanager_id in ( select r.cashflowmanager_id
                                 from   resourcebasei18n r
                                 where  r.name = '4-Persoons Ranchtent' )
```

Comment: Thanks for  the answer  No doubt this is correct but my requirement is to do the same task on pl/sql using loop

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out this is easily accomplished with a single SQL but since *you* require plsql here's an anonymous block for it..

```
declare 
   cursor c_cashflowrule is 
          select c.bookdate_to
            from cashflowrule c
           where (   c.usage_date_from between date '2019-09-29' and date '2020-05-01' 
                  or c.usage_date_to   between date '2019-09-29' and date '2020-05-01' 
                 )
             and exists (select null 
                           from resourcebasei18n r
                          where c.cashflowmanager_id = r.cashflowmanager_id
                            and r.name = '4-Persoons Ranchtent'
                        ) 
            for update of bookdate_to; 
begin 
    for cflow in c_cashflowrule 
    loop
        update cashflowrule 
           set bookdate_to = date '2019-09-29' 
        where current of c_cashflowrule ;
    end loop;
end ;
```